# SQL Query to get largest datatype in schema

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

What is the query to get the top 5 ...data types ...used in a DB by size? 
blob > int

Comment: those are not sql server datatypes, sql server has tinyint, smallint, int and bigint

Comment: @SQLMenace: edited Q...but still what would the query be?

Comment: Why, may I ask? All ints are 4 bytes for example, varchar(200) may have just a few characters in each row etc

Answer (score 0):

The sys.types  and sys.systypes have some of that info, play around with these queries

```
select *
from sys.types

select * 
from sys.systypes
```

Answer (score 0):

What about trying this. It uses the tables `sysobjects`, `syscolumns` and `systypes` to find table name, column name, type and length in bytes. You can select more fields as you need from `syscolumns` or `systypes`.

```
SELECT 
    top 5
    so.name as tablename,
    sc.name as columnname,
    st.name as typename,
    sc.length as columnlength_bytes
FROM 
    syscolumns sc
INNER JOIN
    sysobjects so
    on sc.id = so.id
INNER JOIN
    systypes st
    on sc.xtype = st.xtype
WHERE 
    so.xtype = 'U'
ORDER BY 
    sc.length desc
```